# batch - windows control panel taskkill not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, themes, taskkill

So i'm making a simple batch file that switches themes upon request.
When entered the name of a theme located in the same directory, it runs it using `start` then it opens Control panel to switch theme. It should wait 10 seconds and Taskkill it by the window name (NOTE: im using a Dutch version og windows 7 home: this is basicly the path used as windows title  `Configuratiescherm\Vormgeving en persoonlijke instellingen\Persoonlijke instellingen` ) But after ten seconds, it doesnt kill it, it only output's the following text `Info: er zijn geen taken met de opgegeven criteria actief.` what translates to `Info: there are no processes found with that title`
Help please!

Comment: That is because windows configuration screen is a subprocess of explorer.exe. If you open up your task manager while the configuration screen is open, you should see that one of the apps at the top is called `Windows Verkenner`. If you click the little arrow to the left of it it should show: `Configuratiescherm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real good way to taskkill control panel only. The only one I can think of is killing and restarting explorer.exe using

```
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
```

Comment: I was also thinking about this, but i definitly dont want to mess with explorer.exe still, thanks a lot

Comment: Btw, if you ever find yourself unable to start explorer.exe, you can use Ctrl+Shift+Del, click file, start new task, explorer.exe

Comment: I know. I once accidently killef explorer.exe while clearing memory :)

Answer (score -1):

use these commands

```
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe

start explorer.exe
```

Comment: You just copy pasted the answer from the accepted answer above.